# Widget in listview of Remoteview for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I am having listview with set of items in that. I will send that data using intent to another Activity.How do I get that intent data and put it in AppWidgetProvider. Could anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what type your data is, but for this example let's assume it's a string, and if it's not then we can change the intent slightly.

You're right to use an intent, and I'll show you an example of how to use one.

In the ListView activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, AppWidgetProvider.class);
i.putExtra("Intent Key", stringToBeSent);
```

In the AppWidgetProvider activity:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String myData = i.getStringExtra("Intent Key");
```

Hope it helps.